# Capture keyDown for current page only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have forms on different pages of my applications. Upon pressing 'Enter' or 'Esc', the form on the current page must be 'Submitted' or 'Cancelled'. The keydown() function should be triggered anywhere on the page and not tied to a specific DOM element.

.js

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            // enter pressed
            $('#submitCreateAccountForm').click();
            $('#submitForm').click();
            $('#submitNewSubmissionForm').click();
        }
        if(e.which == 27) {
            // esc pressed

            $('#submitCreateAccountFormCancel').click();
            $('#submitFormCancel').click();
            $('#submitNewSubmissionFormCancel').click();
        }
    });
```

What should 'document' be replaced by? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  $(function(){

    $('html').bind('keypress', function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        //do somethings
      }
      else if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        return false;
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: This still calls keypress function on all pages and not just with the current active page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$("body").keyup(function(event){   // bind keyup event to body 
    if(event.keyCode == 13){       // 13 - code of enter key (find for ESC)
        $("#enter").click();       // bind enter press for clicking botton with id="enter" and corresponding actions
    }
});
```